# Applying ArcGIS Field Calculator on New Records?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.1, field-calculator, esri-geodatabase

I'm using the Field Calculator in ArcMap 10.1 to populate a field with a string version of an existing integer field.  This is working correctly on existing data.

I am looking for a way to have that field populate on new records.

Is it possible to have the Field Calculator automatically populate a field based on a calculation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [Attribute Assistant](http://www.arcgis.com/home/item.html?id=e35580f27bce4782b95ea8296ac60927) add on to do this.